# IBM Domino: Error When Submit Document

Tags: lotus-domino

I create a new database, and when I create a document and submit to this database from the web, I got an error in the console:

> HTTP Web Server: IBM Notes Exception - The certificate table does not contain enough valid certificates to verify the public key of its owner.

But if I submit a document to another database in this server, I can save successfully. Where can I setup or need do some other step? When I open a form in this new database, I also got this error in a message box. I tried to change ACL for the new database but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting this error while attempting HTTP access to a specific database, it probably means that there is something odd about the signature on one or more design elements in the database. I.e., the signature on the form, the query save agent, or some other design element was done with an id that doesn't share a common root certificate with the server.

Try using the Domino Administrator client to sign the database, either with the server id or with another id in the same organization.